# How to use ZooKeeper with Hadoop for sharing a read/write variable among reducers

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-zookeeper

My question is:
How can I use ZooKeeper with Hadoop, such that all reducers can getData() / setData() to one shared znode?

My use case is that I need to share a global read/write variable among reducers in my MapReduce job. I am trying to use ZooKeeper for this purpose. 
I created a ZooKeeper object that creates a znode and gives it an initial value. Next step is that I need all reducers to be able to getData() / setData() for this znode. This requires passing the ZooKeeper object to all reducers, which I don't know how to do it. I tried to serialize the ZooKeeper object and pass it to reducers (through Configuration properties or through distributed cache), but ZooKeeper class is not serializable.

ZooKeeper tutorials and all examples I could find illustrate ZooKeeper with multi-threaded applications, but none of them show how to use ZooKeeper with mappers or reducers.

Comment: This is not an answer, but could be an useful link http://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.1.2/zookeeperTutorial.html#sc_producerConsumerQueues

Comment: Thanks a lot Arun for your help, I already came across this example before. harpun's answer corrected a misunderstanding i had and solved my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot pass the `ZooKeeper` object itself to the mappers/reducers. Just identify the config needed to instantiate the `ZooKeeper` object  within the mapper/reducer (like `connectionString`) and pass it via `Configuration` properties.

The interaction with ZooKeeper within mapper/reducers does not differ from the a usual Java program.

Comment: Thanks a lot harpun. I had a few misunderstandings as I am new to ZooKeeper. Your answer cleared things up to me and solved my problem

Comment: You're welcome! :) BTW. remember to upvote any answer you found useful on SO. Thanks!